# Actual size of BigQuery table's snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BQ [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-intro) states that

```
Storage costs apply for table snapshots, but BigQuery only charges for data in a table snapshot that no longer exists in its base table, or that has changed in its base table
```

Is there any way (UI/programmatic) to check storage size of given snapshot (storage I am billed for)? When checking table's metadata I see `size` entry which only tells me the size of the base table at the moment of taking snapshot.

Example:
`base_table` size: 22GB
`base_table_snapshot` size: 22GB

then after addition of some data to `base_table` UI shows

`base_table` size: 24GB
`base_table_snapshot` size: 22GB

but 22GB was already snapshotted (and did not change), so I should be billed for 24GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the info of the true cost (for now). In fact it works as a Git commit. It take a snapshot at a point of time. All the new data aren't take into account.

All the changes (update/delete) in the current table that create a diff with the snapshot are stored. You are charged of all that diffs.

More your change your existing snapshotted data, more you pay. If you never change the past, the snapshot are free.

Comment: Hello I'm a bit lost,
does it mean when we write truncate the whole table, we going to get charge for the whole snapshot storage?

Comment: yes, all the data are modified, so Snapshot keep a copy of each of them. That's the principle of a backup, if you perform a write truncate with the wrong data, you want to get back to the previous ones

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I have other doubts. what if we truncate the whole table with the same existing table. like ```select * from a```, write_truncate to table a, meanwhile I have snapshot table a_snapshot. Am I still going to get charged even the whole data still the same including the value and rows?